# Base Algorithm Scripting by chopping the array with splice function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

Now I am working on a exercise in freecodecamp. Currently I got an logical error but do not why the failure happens.

In the code,I have to build in a function, which chop the input array based on the parameter. The testing result should be as follows:

```
chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2) should return [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]].
chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3) should return [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]].
chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 4) should return [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8]].
chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2) should return [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8]].
```

And my code are as follows:

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var array = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length ; x+=size){
    var spliceArr = arr.splice(0,size);
    array.push(spliceArr);
  }
  array.push(arr);
  return array;
}

chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d","e"], 2);
```

For most of the conditions, the code works. But for the last condition i.e

```
chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2) should return [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8]].
```

in this case I cannot get the correct answer. I tested in console log, and turn out the output is like

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8]].
```

I know that it is not a difficult question and there are lots of better way to approach it, but can I know what is the logic fallancy in this code?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to add a `console.log(arr)` to your loop to see how the array changes over time.

You would see that it looks like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Then, take into account your final splice and add which occurs outside of the loop:

```
[6, 7, 8]
```

Since your loop increments by `size`, it will exit once it has gathered all subarrays of exactly `size`.

Instead, I would recommend continuing until your input is empty:

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var array = [];
  while(arr.length > 0){
    var spliceArr = arr.splice(0,size);
    array.push(spliceArr);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `splice` use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). This will also guarantees that the original array is not modified.

Like this (*working demo*):

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var array = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x += size) {
     // take elements from current index (`x`) to `x` + `size`
     // (do not remove them from the original array, so the original size is not modified either)
    var sliceArr = arr.slice(x, x + size);
    array.push(sliceArr);
  }
  return array;
}


console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2)); //should return [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]].
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)); // should return [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]].
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 4)); // should return [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8]].
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2)); // should return [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to step using the size to save on the number of loops through the array. We are also saving the length so it's not fetched each time as it saves operations. Also you will notice that I'm not using `var` as you shouldn't be using it. Please use `let` for normal variables and `const` for variables you are not going to reassign.

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  let array = [];
  let arrayLength = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i+=size) {
    array.push(arr.slice(i, i+size));
  }
  return array
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2), [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]])
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3), [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 4), [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8]])
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2), [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8]])
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are reducing the array length throughout your iteration. I.e. your array gets smaller within each iteration while your x continously increases. That means that before your last iteration your x will be at 6 and the array length will be 3, hence `x < arr.length` evaluates to `false` and your last iteration does not happen. The most simplistic solution that I can think of is to store the original array length into a variable I named `stop` and remove the unneccessary final array push outside the loop.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var array = [];
  var stop = arr.length;
  for (var x = 0; x < stop; x+=size){
    var spliceArr = arr.splice(0,size);
    array.push(spliceArr);
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

`splice` method changes the length of array on every iteration. That's why your loop exits before you expect. You can read more about splice [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Unlike `splice`, `slice` will not remove items from the array that's why lealceldeiro answer will work as expected.

Kevin Bruccoleri answer looks cleaner and shorter but if you have an app where you store an array in to a variable and then pass it to the function, that variable will be empty after the execution of the function, which can lead to bugs in your app. That's why arrays are basically object, but that's science fiction of javascript.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var array = [];
  while (arr.length) {
    array.push(arr.splice(0, size))
  }
  return array
}

var nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
console.log('now it full', nums);
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(nums, 2));
console.log('now it empty', nums);
```

Answer (score -1):

Used `slice` to copy original array two
`map()` and `splice()` to insert array from n index

```
const frankenSplice = (arr1, arr2, n) => {
    let arr = arr2.slice();

    arr1.map(e => {
        arr.splice(n, 0, e);
        n++;
    })

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it